# Why are there so many Hibernate Session Metrics logged?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

In a Spring Boot 3 application using Hibernate 6 I've set Hibernate to generate statistics and according to Vlad Mihalcea's [The Open Session In View Anti-Pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern) I've disabled `open-in-view`:

```yaml
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics: true
spring.jpa.open-in-view: false
```

My question now is, why there are so many `Session Metrics` logged to the console. Since the vast majority of them are just saying that there was nothing done at all, not even a simple flush, I tend to think that there is no performance problem but more something going on behind I just don't know yet.

The logged `Session Metrics` for a simple read operation initiated via an mvc request including the SQL statement look like that:

```
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                                 :  Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                         :  Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                         :  Completed initialization in 1 ms
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] Spring Security Debugger                          :  

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/dev/cache/BANNED':

org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@410f399d

servletPath:/dev/cache/BANNED

accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1

Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]

************************************************************

01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/dev/**'], Mvc [pattern='/test/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@315139e2, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@50b1aea, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2572d409, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5e02753c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@27129ef5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@14d6f58f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7677a485, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@88d92e5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6dc82d99, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@182711f5, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@38f183e9]] (1/5)
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Securing GET /dev/cache/BANNED
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking CsrfFilter (5/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.c.CsrfFilter                              :  Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking LogoutFilter (6/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.l.LogoutFilter                          :  Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache                 :  matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager:  Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@44e47200]
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager:  Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@44e47200] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1825/0x0000000801828c90@1bee9f91
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Secured GET /dev/cache/BANNED
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] t.h.s.f.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:  Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/users/authenticate']
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    40034 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] .s.a.m.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor:  Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.example.tryout.controller.mvc._dev.DevController.cacheTest1(java.lang.String); target is of class [com.example.tryout.controller.mvc._dev.DevController]
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] .s.a.m.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor:  Authorized method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.example.tryout.controller.mvc._dev.DevController.cacheTest1(java.lang.String); target is of class [com.example.tryout.controller.mvc._dev.DevController]
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] a.p.t.h.c.m._.DevController                       :  Query Cache Testing Now...
inside email status service
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.SQL                                           :  
    select
        e1_0.email_status_id,
        e1_0.description 
    from
        email_status e1_0 
    where
        e1_0.description=?
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.o.j.bind                                      :  binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [BANNED]
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.s.i.StatisticsImpl                            :  HHH000117: HQL: [CRITERIA] select e1_0.email_status_id,e1_0.description from email_status e1_0 where e1_0.description=?, time: 1ms, rows: 1
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    10520 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    30975 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    98771 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    686424 nanoseconds spent performing 2 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    55230 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] a.p.t.h.c.m._.DevController                       :  {emailStatusId=5, description=BANNED}
01:37:04 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-5] a.p.t.h.c.m._.DevController                       :  Cache Testing Done...
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository    :  No HttpSession currently exists
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext         :  Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext         :  Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
01:37:04 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter           :  Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] Spring Security Debugger                          :  

************************************************************

New HTTP session created: 0fccd0a8-d7f9-418e-9b03-5e846a446ac5

************************************************************

01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    12858 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    8182 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:04 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-5] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    13443 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:05 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-6] Spring Security Debugger                          :  

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/js/famous-scripts.js':

org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@332e8370

servletPath:/js/famous-scripts.js

accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
sec-fetch-dest: script
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin

Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]

************************************************************

01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/dev/**'], Mvc [pattern='/test/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@315139e2, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@50b1aea, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2572d409, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5e02753c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@27129ef5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@14d6f58f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7677a485, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@88d92e5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6dc82d99, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@182711f5, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@38f183e9]] (1/5)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Ant [pattern='/admin/h2/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@38421084, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@32e8c3c3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5ca64b79, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6bd5101f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7c1ac3b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@422179c7, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2a447744, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@44eb9af1, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@73536bcc, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@4790a29a]] (2/5)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/favicon.ico'], Mvc [pattern='/css/**'], Mvc [pattern='/fonts/**'], Mvc [pattern='/img/**'], Mvc [pattern='/js/**'], Mvc [pattern='/webjars/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2396e6e1, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@343f01c7, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@197d38a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@74197f00, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1dbef39d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1c486cec, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@55f066b4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@52ac57e7]] (3/5)
01:37:05 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Securing GET /js/famous-scripts.js
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (2/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking CsrfFilter (3/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.c.CsrfFilter                              :  Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking LogoutFilter (4/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.l.LogoutFilter                          :  Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (5/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (6/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (7/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Invoking AuthorizationFilter (8/8)
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager:  Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@484622c6]
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] w.a.i.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager:  Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@484622c6] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1825/0x0000000801828c90@1bee9f91
01:37:05 DEBUG - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                          :  Secured GET /js/famous-scripts.js
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] t.h.s.f.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:  Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/users/authenticate']
01:37:05 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    15488 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:05 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    15780 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:05 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter           :  Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=0fccd0a8-d7f9-418e-9b03-5e846a446ac5], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
01:37:05 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    12566 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
01:37:05 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-6] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    7013 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Can it be, that Hibernate does a lot of things behind the scene which triggers `Session Metrics`, especially when the application is doing `request/response` work like in this example, where a JavaScript file was requested from the server after the initial database action and although there was no database interaction at all, `Server Metrics` got involved?

Can anyone explain why Hibernate behaves this way and whether I have to take some action or everything is allright anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "extra" sessions may have various causes, for example if the business service does not declare transactions, then your Spring Data JPA repositories may, hence Hibernate sessions get created.

To figure out where these sessions come from, you can simply use a breapoint in the `end()` method of Hibernate `StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener` and have a look at the execution stack.

If you simply want to get rid of the "empty" session metrics logs, you can use your own implementation of Hibernate Session metrics logger. See my article https://www.adeliosys.fr/articles/hibernate-monitoring/ and my custom metrics logger https://github.com/fbeaufume/hibernate-monitoring/blob/main/src/main/java/com/adeliosys/sample/CustomSessionEventListener.java#L221 (line 221 shows how to ignore "empty" sessions).